# Fixing SharePoint site collection restoration which is stuck in read only mode

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to restore site collection from .bak file(80gb). Power-shell restore command is not completing (more that 12 hours) and is still executing.

Site is now in read-only mode. I doubt it is stuck somewhere. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you try restoring directly from SQL Server?

Comment: What Command you executed in PS ?

I restored with this command which I got from **Technet**


`**Restore-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionURL> -Path <BackupFile>  -Force**`

Comment: Did you mount the DB? Is it a migration? Are u 2010 e 13? Please provide some more details. (eg post the powershell command u used)